# If $X$ infinite dimensional and $F\colon X\to\mathbb{F}^{n}$ linear, then $\ker(F)$ infinite dimensional subspace of $X$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, quotient-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

Suppose that $X$ is an infinite dimensional vectorspace over the field $\mathbb{F}$ (real or complex numbers). Let $F\colon X\to\mathbb{F}^{n}$ be a linear map. I want to prove that $\ker(F)$ is an infinite dimensional subspace of $X$.

I tried to use the fact that $X/\ker(F)$ and $F(X)$ are isomorphic, but I can't come up with a neat argument. I really want to avoid cardinal arithmetic, i.e. things like "$\infty-n=\infty$" that may show up when you use the "generalized" rank-nullity theorem.

So my question is: Is there a neat (and perhaps short) argument to prove that $\ker(F)$ can not be finite dimensional? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write $X = \operatorname{ker}(F) \oplus V$ for some vector space $V$. Do you know how to finish? (Of course, an immediate corollary of this is the rank-nullity theorem.)

Comment: Why is it always possible to decompose (an infinite dimensional v.s.) $X$ as $\ker(F)\oplus V$ for some v.s. $V$? Is this a consequence of $X/\ker(F)\cong\text{Im}(F)$? And how do I finish if I assume that $\ker(F)\oplus V$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Mindlack‘s answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_1, \ldots, u_p \in X$ be such that $F (u_1),\ldots,F(u_p)$ is a basis of the image of $F$.

Then, show $X=\bigoplus_{i=1}^p{\mathbb{F}u_i} \oplus \ker{F}$.